# web scraping using mechanize error in code

Tags: python, mechanize

```
import mechanize
br=mechanize.Browser()
r=br.open("http://www.drugs.com/search-wildcard-phonetic.html")
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['searchterm']='panadol'
br.submit()
print br.response().read()
```

---

```
error in above code:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mech2.py", line 6, in <module>
    br.submit()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 541, in submit
    return self.open(self.click(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 255, in _mech_open
    raise response
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: request disallowed by robots.txt
```

please help to correct the above code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is nothing wrong with your code. Your error message

> mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: request disallowed by robots.txt

Looks like you are contravening the [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) file. If you don't want to see this error message, stop abusing this website and perhaps contact them for an acceptable way of using their data.